# ddms heap view for hello world 8MB+ allocated

Tags: heap-memory, shared-memory, ddms

I created a simple hello world app using eclipse for android.
I am seeing 8MB+ heap space used in ddms heap view when launching this application.
There are no assets added and its a simple textview.
Does this 8MB include some shared memory from framework like the framework resources?
I cannot account for 8MB otherwise ....

thanks